# race conditions using std::mbrtowc on gcc only

Tags: c, gcc, race-condition, glibc

I'm getting race conditions when using the [stl wide char library functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtowc). Here's a minimal reproducible example in c, where I mention the compilers I've tried, the library version, and the expected and received outputs:

```c
// temp.cpp

#include <wchar.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char utf8[] = {'a'};
    wchar_t output[1];
    mbstate_t ps;
    size_t ret = mbrtowc(output, utf8, 1, &ps);
    assert(ret == 1);
    assert(output[0] == L'a');
    return 0;

    // let me define BAD output as:

        // most of the time (~9/10), I get the following error:
        //      a.out: ../iconv/loop.c:457: utf8_internal_loop_single: Assertion `inptr - bytebuf > (state->__count & 7)' failed.
        //      Aborted (core dumped)

        // the other (~1/10 times) the program ends correctly (exit code 0)

    // and let me define GOOD output as:

        // the program ends correctly (exit code 0), always
    
    // compiler     output
    //
    // gcc-7        BAD
    // gcc-9        BAD
    // gcc-10       BAD
    // clang-10     GOOD
    // clang-12     GOOD

    // compile command: gcc temp.cpp
    //                  clang temp.cpp


    // gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
    // glibc version: 2.31
}
```

My questions are as follow:

- Can anyone else reproduce this, or is it just me?
- What is the meaning of the assertion being tripped?
- Why is this happening?

Edit: ah, c++ default ctors have spoiled me. (also, in my original source I was working with std::mbrtowc, which threw me off.

Introspection: I will indeed use valgrind more in these cases.

Comment: Tagged as C but filename is .cpp, confused.

Comment: it C not C++. C++is a different language. Rename to temp.c to do not confuse compiler.

Comment: cant reproduce any using any compiler version: https://godbolt.org/z/7soWrsq9z

Comment: There is no race condition there

Comment: It can't be a race condition if there is no concurrent execution - there are no multiple threads or processes in this program.  You merely have a bug that triggers unpredictably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `ps`.

[`man mbrtowc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbrtowc.3.html):

> In all of the above cases, if `ps` [fourth argument] is `NULL`, a static anonymous
> state known only to the `mbrtowc()` function is used instead.
> **Otherwise, `*ps` must be a valid `mbstate_t` object.**  An `mbstate_t`
> object `a` can be initialized to the initial state by zeroing it,
> for example using

```
       memset(&a, 0, sizeof(a));
```

Your object `ps` is uninitialized and therefore cannot in general be a valid `mbstate_t` object.

`valgrind` detects this bug.